# hasNext() method confusion

Tags: java, oop, io

I can't seem to get my for loop to populate a string array with certain lines of text. For clarity: inputFile is a file that I have read in that looks somewhat like this:

```
3
Bob
121
124
124 
Susan
454
241
524
Richie
789 
124 
547
```

The 3 indicates how many "students" there are in the file which is while my starting value is 1 not 0.

actualFile is the string array that I want the various names stored in. 
Here is my code.

Note: I do NOT want to use array lists for this. Just arrays.

```
    for (int z = 1; inputFile.hasNext(); z = z +3) {
    actualFile(z) = actualFile +  "\n" + inputFile;
    }
    System.out.println(actualFile);
```

I want the final output to look something like this:

```
Bob
Susan
Richie
```

EDIT Replay to Jordon Johns:
I don't get any output with the fixed code of:

```
    String [] actualFile = new String [50];
    for (int z = 1; inputFile.hasNext(); z = z +3) {
        actualFile[z]= actualFile +  "\n" + inputFile;
    }
    System.out.println(actualFile);
```

I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52
```

The inputFile is a file that I have prepared as such:

```
    System.out.print("Enter file name: "); 
    String userFile = in.nextLine(); 
    File file = new File(userFile); 
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: How much do you know about Java syntax and arrays?

Comment: @SotiriousDelimanlois I'm just a beginner. It's possible I'm just missing something very simple here that I already know.

Comment: What do you think `actualFile(z) =` does and why do you think so?

Comment: I believe that `actualFile(z)` says to store the information to the right based on the increment that the for loop is on. I think that because that's how it works in matlab.

Comment: This feels like an assignment?  At any rate, what exactly is the problem?  actualFile(z) is not valid syntax unless actualFile() happens to be some method.  actualFile[z] is what you probably meant.  Provide more details as to what has you stuck.  (what is your output?)

Comment: I believe this will really help here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @JordanJohns yes that is what I meant do to. However, now I get an out of bound error even though I thought I made the array plenty large enough. I will edit the post above to clarify what I need further.

Comment: If you have `hasNext()` then you probably need some kind of `next()` call somewhere as well. Maybe even four times more than the size of the resulting array, no?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the program, or printing the output as the loop is running to see what is happening?

What you want is simple.  But its important you take the steps to understand how to get there.

As Solitirious is suggesting, what do you think that line of code inside the for loop does?  What *is* "inputFile"?  I don't think its the value you want.  You want a String.  Given the type that is "inputFile", what methods do you have access to (or attributes) that can give you its string value?

Comment: @JordanJohns Replay to your question is in an edit above.

Comment: I made the last edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing something like this. I don't know why not use an `ArrayList` though...

```
int maxZ = inputFile.nextInt(), z = 0;

while(inputFile.hasNext()){
  if(!inputFile.hasNextInt()){
    if(z < maxZ){
        actualFile[z] = inputFile.next();
        z++;
    }
  }
  else inputFile.next();
}

for(int i = 0; i < actualFile.length; i++){
    System.out.println(actualFile[i]);
}
```

**NOTES:** This is a terrible approach and will almost always result in a exception and that is why an `ArrayList` would be better here.

You can't print an array like you are trying to do. You have to cycle through it printing each element.